# nginx + php-fpm Rewrite rule not working

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have this conf,

```
    rewrite "^download/([0-9a-f]{32})/(.+)$" /download.php?h=$1&f=$2 last;
    location / {
            index index.html;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.apache.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.html;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $root_path$request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

But when I try open url, `http://example.com/download/d3ef6bbeaff9b429680bca646e8ee1cf/video.mp4`
It's return `404 Not Found`
I tried put `rule` in any `location`, but it's not helped.
Direct link to file `http://example.com/download.php` is working, what need to do for work `rewrite` ?
I saw many threads about it, but solutions not helped me, whats wrong?

On server nginx + php-fpm

Comment: URIs always begin with slash, so you should fix your regexp`rewrite "^/download..."`

Comment: @AlexeyTen the same, `404 Not Found`

Comment: Turn [`rewrite_log on`](http://nginx.org/r/rewrite_log) and see in `error.log` for details.

Comment: @AlexeyTen no new logs in `error.log`. I restart `nginx` after added `rewrite_log on;`

Comment: Have you changed `error_log` directive to write `notice` level? It defaults to `error` level, so you need to change it too

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I think when i changed regexp, i don't restart `nginx`, and after I changed it again. Now It works, solution is your first post. Thanks. Can you post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx's rewrite always match full URI that starts with slash. So you need to fix your rewrite:

```
rewrite "^/download/([0-9a-f]{32})/(.+)$" /download.php?h=$1&f=$2 last;
```